# Python program using Spark working on MacOS and not on Linux

Tags: python, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm using Apache Spark 2.0.2 and Zookeeper 3.4.9 in a standlone cluster for testing. I couldn't find in the documentations something different between the two, but this line shot out an error as follows:

```
self.classes = self.sc.broadcast(items.map(lambda x: list(zip(x[0][1], [x[1]]*len(x[0][1])))).groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], set(x[1]))).collectAsMap())
```

Error (part of the output, it repeats itself):

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:390)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1899)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1913)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Remembering that in MacOS this works normally and the configurations are identical as they can.

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. As someone (forgot the user) said, I could break into bits and test it, but the error still would be the different output on MacOS and Ubuntu. Besides, I tried to debug that way, didn't work.

Comment: with a one-liner that is over 150 characters(!), it seems that breaking it out into chunks is the best way to debug it.

Comment: I don't want a solution, I merely asked if there is a difference between the OS and pointed why I was asking.